# CodeIgniter - Active Query fails unless I slow it down with garbage on screen. Why?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is where I am having a problem in CodeIgniter.
My function get_applicable_menu_xml() calls deals_sorting_counts_deal() which does a complex query to get a result set.  The num_rows() of that set is returned to be used when generating an XML string for later use in outputting a drop down selector.

For some reason, this fails, appearing to display a blank screen which never stops loading.

But, even stranger if I un-comment the line //print $this->db->last_query(); from just before I return the num_rows(), the code works.
And, YES, I know it's normal to get all kinds of 'Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...' messages along with the SQL used, but with that the page loads, the numbers all get returned, etc. Without it, the page does NOT load and appears to fail to finsih connecting as if the server is not responding.

My question: what could possibly cause that to happen?
I've spent days trying to debug this.

Note as well, this does not happen on my local WAMP server, or on the Rackspace Linux server for the DEV/QA sites.  It ONLY happens on the Rackspace Linux server where the live site is hosted.  I've looked around, but cannot find any specific setting that is different that may explain its unique behavior.  But, I'm not a Linux server expert.  I'm just a competent user.

Firebug is no help as the page isn't loading far enough for anything to show.

Can anyone provide a reasoning behind this odd behaviour?
Thanks,
Al Pieroway

```
            //from my database.php file (but i've played with all these)

            $db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
            $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
            $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
            $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
            $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
            $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
            $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
            $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
            $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

            //the meat of the problem these functions are in
            //my models/general_model.php file

            function get_applicable_menu_xml($city_sef,$btype_sef,$search_id,$days,$time,$offset,$perpage,$sort_type,$emp_lat,$emp_long,$radius=30,$merchant_list)
            {
                $xml = "<menu>";
                $parent_cats = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `business_type` WHERE `btype_parent` = 0");
                foreach($parent_cats->result_array() as $parent_cat)
                {
                    $cat_count = $this->deals_sorting_counts_deal($city_sef,$parent_cat['btype_sef'],$search_id,$days,$time,$offset,$perpage,$sort_type,$emp_lat,$emp_long,$radius,$merchant_list);
                    $sub_cats = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `business_type` WHERE `btype_parent` = ".$parent_cat['btype_id']);
                    if($sub_cats->num_rows()>0) {
                        $xml .= "<category id='".$parent_cat['btype_id']."' name='".htmlentities($parent_cat['btype_name'], ENT_QUOTES)."' btype-sef='".$parent_cat['btype_sef']."' count='".$cat_count."'>";
                        foreach($sub_cats->result_array() as $sub_cat)
                        { 
                            $sub_cat_count = $this->deals_sorting_counts_deal($city_sef,$sub_cat['btype_sef'],$search_id,$days,$time,$offset,$perpage,$sort_type,$emp_lat,$emp_long,$radius,$merchant_list);
                            $xml .= "<subcategory id='".$sub_cat['btype_id']."' name='".htmlentities($sub_cat['btype_name'], ENT_QUOTES)."' btype-sef='".$sub_cat['btype_sef']."' count='".$sub_cat_count."'></subcategory>";
                        }
                        $xml .= "</category>";
                    }
                }
                $xml .= "</menu>";
                return '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'.$xml;
            }


            function deals_sorting_counts_deal($city_sef,$btype_sef,$search_id,$days,$time,$offset,$perpage,$sort_type,$emp_lat,$emp_long,$radius=30,$merchant_list)
            {    
                $sql11 = 'SET OPTION SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1';
                $this->db->query($sql11);/**/

                $today = substr(date('l',mktime(0,0,0)),0,3);
                if ($today=='Mon') { $day_to = 1; }
                elseif($today=='Tue') { $day_to = 2; }
                elseif($today=='Wed') { $day_to = 3; }
                elseif($today=='Thu') { $day_to = 4; }
                elseif($today=='Fri') { $day_to = 5; }
                elseif($today=='Sat') { $day_to = 6; }
                elseif($today=='Sun') { $day_to = 7; }
                $string_IN ='';
                if($btype_sef!='all') {
                    $string_IN .= $btype_sef.",";
                    $next_id = 0;
                    $this->db->select('btype_id');
                    $this->db->from('business_type');
                    $this->db->where('btype_sef',$btype_sef);
                    $result_id = $this->db->get();
                    if($result_id->num_rows()>0)
                    {
                        $row_id = $result_id->row();
                        $next_id = $row_id->btype_id;
                        $this->db->select('btype_sef');
                        $this->db->from('business_type');
                        $this->db->where('btype_parent',$next_id);
                        $result_str = $this->db->get();
                        if($result_str->num_rows()>0)
                        {
                            foreach($result_str->result_array() as $result_s)
                            {
                                $btype_sef_shild = $result_s['btype_sef'];
                                $string_IN .= $btype_sef_shild.",";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $string_IN = substr($string_IN,0,-1);
                    $IN_ARRAY = explode(',',$string_IN); 
                }
                if($this->session->userdata('emp_lat')!='' and $this->session->userdata('emp_long')!='') {
                    $fLat = $emp_lat;
                    $fLon = $emp_long;
                }
                else {
                    $fLat = $emp_lat;
                    $fLon = $emp_long;
                }
                $this->session->set_userdata('emp_long',$emp_long);
                $com_id = $this->session->userdata('comp_id');
                $this->db->select('vendor.longitude,vendor.latitude,deals.is_time,deals.deal_img,deals.deal_avilable_custom,vendor.vendor_desc,deals.status_id as check3 ,deal_company.deal_id as deal_id,deal_company.comp_id as cmp, vendor.vendor_image,vendor.vendor_id,vendor.vendor_city_id,vendor.vendor_business_type_id,vendor.vendor_state_id,vendor.vendor_business_name,deals.start_date_time,deals.end_date_time,deals.deal_id,dtype_id,deal_name,deal_detail,deals.terms,deals.status_id,deal_sef,hero_emp_id,hero_comp_id,business_type.btype_name,deal_availabe.available_id');
                $this->db->from('deals');
                $this->db->join('vendor','vendor.vendor_id=deals.vendor_id');
                $this->db->join('business_type','vendor.vendor_business_parent_type_id=business_type.btype_id OR vendor.vendor_business_child_type_id=business_type.btype_id OR vendor.vendor_business_parent_type_id1=business_type.btype_id OR vendor.vendor_business_child_type_id1=business_type.btype_id OR vendor.corporate_parent_category_id=business_type.btype_id OR vendor.corporate_child_category_id=business_type.btype_id' );
                $this->db->join('deal_availabe','deal_availabe.deal_id=deals.deal_id');
                $this->db->join('deal_company','deal_company.deal_id=deals.deal_id');
                $this->db->where('deal_company.comp_id',$com_id);
                $this->db->where('vendor.status_id',1);
                if ($search_id!='')
                {
                    $term = $this->db->escape_like_str(strip_tags($search_id));
                    $this->db->where("(deals.deal_name LIKE '%{$term}%' OR vendor.vendor_business_name LIKE '%{$term}%')");
                }
                if($btype_sef!='all')
                {
                    if($string_IN=='')
                    {
                        $this->db->where('business_type.btype_sef',$btype_sef);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->db->where_in('business_type.btype_sef', $IN_ARRAY);
                    }
                }
                if($days!='all')
                {
                    $this->session->set_userdata('day_check',$days);
                    $this->db->where('deal_availabe.available_id',$days);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->session->set_userdata('day_check','');
                }
                if($time!='all')
                {
                    $this->db->where('deal_timeofday.tod_id',$time);
                }
                if($city_sef!='' && $city_sef!='all')
                {
                    $names = array(0, $city_sef);
                }
                else
                {   
                    $names = array(0, 1);
                }
                $this->db->where('deals.status_id',1);
                $date_starting = time();
                $this->db->where('end_date_time >=', $date_starting);
                $this->db->where('start_date_time <=', $date_starting);
                $this->db->group_by('deals.deal_id');
                $this->db->order_by('deals.is_feature','asc');
                $this->db->limit($perpage,$offset);
                $result = $this->db->get() or die("huh");
                //print $this->db->last_query();
                return $result->num_rows();
            }
```

Comment: It's not specifically mentioned what `sql` error you get but `headers sent` error you've mentioned here, which occurs if you try to send/modify `header` after `header` has been sent already. Once you echo something on the server, `php` sends the header information to the browser and after that you can't modify the header. So, please try to be more specific errors and describe it one individually. [One article about header sent error here](http://heera.it/headers-error-wordpress) to give you an idea which is written for `WordPress` but idea is same.

Comment: Also, a Google search result about [CodeIgniter header sent error](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=codeigniter+header+sent+error&rlz=1C1KMZB_enBD539BD539&oq=codeigniter+header+sent+error&aqs=chrome..69i57.12487j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Yes, the issue is not the header sent error.  I know that error will occur if I try to modify the header.  As stated, that was the ONLY way to get the actual function to work-by echoing last_query() as the function iterates through the sub categories.
I can't figure out why it works with printed junk on the screen, but not without.
I can't tell what error is the cause as CI is terrible for debugging in my opinion.
Is the cause a fatal error which prevents the real error from being thrown?
I need help on how to debug this, if not someone saying they have the answer based on previous experience.